# insert data from while loop into database php

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I am trying to post data into my database from these while loop. It helps me get the monthly periods within a particular range. I want to pick the dates and input the dates into my database along with additional data. I am stuck, please go easy on me.

```
 // Calculate interest
$intrest_loan = $loan_amount * $intrest / 100;
$monthly_payment = $loan_amount / $tenor;

// echo $intrest_loan;
// echo $monthly_payment;

$date = $start;

while ($date <= $end)
{
    $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date . ' +1 month'));
    // echo $date . "\n";
    $sql = "insert into collection (period, amount_collected) values ($date, $monthly_payment)";
    $resultn = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
    if($resultn) {

    }else{
        echo "<p>Failed to load collections</p>";
    }
}
```

Edited code.

Comment: Well, first you'll need to connect to your database, and then in your for loop you either need to execute that query you have, or you need to add to it to an SQL transaction (to keep from bogging down your server). Currently, you're just writing SQL to a variable and not doing anything with it. You may find [this article](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo) helpful in learning PDO.

Comment: why 2 loops? they don't really work together as they are - combine the sql insert into the former loop

Comment: It looks like you're trying to accumulate something into an array, but you never declare an array. `$dates = []` and then `$dates[] = $start` is more like what you want, then iterating over `foreach ($dates as $date)`.

Comment: @RamRaider I would do that. Execute the query as indicated above in one loop would be correct?

Comment: Yes, more or less I think it would - though you ought to use `prepared statements` rather  than directly embedding potentially exploitable(?) variables in the sql

Comment: @tadman I am not trying to accumulate into an array

Comment: It looks like you are when you use things like `count($date)`, which is used to [count elements in an array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php). I'm just trying to read your code here, and not much of it makes sense. When you say "monthly periods" that translates to "I need to insert multiple records spaced out over time" as in "I need to insert from an array of dates".

Comment: @RamRaider It doesn't matter if they're exploitable or not, what matters is that they're data and they don't belong in the query. Placeholder values solve a wide range of problems, one of which is exploits.

Comment: @RamRaider thanks for the advice I would do that. Made an edit to the code

Comment: @tadman you are correct with that analysis

Comment: You can either stage the values into an array, then insert from that array, or you can loop around a place where you execute a prepared statement multiple times. Both approaches are valid. I'd recommend writing a function to emit the array, and another function to insert the array, as these are much easier to test independently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are using `mysqli` then I hope this might help. In keeping with comments made regarding the 2 disconnected loops you can/should combine into a single loop where the date value is calculated and used as input for the sql statement. As you posted a snippet of code rather than the full thing it is impossible to say if your sql is vulnerable to sql injection or not but where money is involved it would be wise to take no chances and try to mitigate against malicious attacks - thus use a `prepared statement.`

The `DateTime` class has a variety of methods to help manipulate the date and in this case the addition of a month can be done very cleanly as shown below.

In essence you create the sql statement with placeholders (`?`) and bind those placeholders to variables at runtime. Once the statement is prepared it can be executed as many times as required with little extra overhead.

```
/* some example / dummy dates ~ source unknown */
$str_date_start='2020-01-01';
$str_date_end='2021-01-01';


/* create a prepared statement */
$sql='insert into `collection` ( `period`, `amount_collected` ) values (?,?)';
$stmt=$conn->prepare( $sql );
$stmt->bind_param( 'ss', $date, $monthly_payment );     

/* original repayment calculations - corrected spelling of interest*/
$interest_loan = $loan_amount * $interest / 100;
$monthly_payment = $loan_amount / $tenor;


/* create new date objects */
$start=new DateTime( $str_date_start );
$end=new DateTime( $str_date_end );
$interval=new DateInterval('P1M');

/* make sure we start AT the start */
$start->sub( $interval );

while( $start < $end ){
    $start->add( $interval );
    $date=$start->format('Y-m-d 00:00:00');
    $stmt->execute();
}
$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
```

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly even with my tweaks, neat code.